# Php and stored routines

Tags: php, sql

I'm working with Mysql and PHP and I got a problem fetching the results from a stored procedure call.
With `mysql_num_rows()` it doesn't work because I always get `1`(boolean), so I'm asking if there's another way to retrieve the result set.

Code:

```
$ris=mysql_query("CALL search_person('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]', '$_POST[adress]', '$_POST[telephone]')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with your stored procedure?

Comment: Do you want to get the values for some out parameters? Stored procedures don't have return values.

Answer (score 0):

Change the procedure to a function and return

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

as the result of the function to php script.